# Laravel 5 proper way to require CSS file from view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I've got specific `Form` component, which is declared as

```
Form::component('fcRadio', 'components.form.fcradio', ['name', 'options', 'selected' => null]);
```

and used as

```
{{ Form::fcRadio('name', $options }}
```

What I want is somehow attach custom CSS file, so if the page fires this component at least once, the desired CSS file is included to the `<head>` of my document.

For example, in Joomla it was like

```
$this->document->addStylesheet('my_awesome_style.css');
```

Is there any way to achieve the same in Laravel?

**UPD:**

I've extended the answers below a bit to let it add multiple styles from multiple templates. Finally, it looks like this:

```
@section('styles')
@parent
{{HTML::style('css/fcradio.css')}}
@stop
```

It works fine, but if I use the component twice per page, style is also adds twice. How can I allow multiple but unique entries?

Comment: This should be dealt on client side using javascript/jQuery. Is that an option for you?

Comment: @Rahi why do you think this should be on client-side?

Comment: Because you want to add to <head> tag unless you are ok with adding it in the <body>.

Comment: @Rahl Well, sections in laravel allows adding content to head as well as `$this->document->addStyleshee` in joomla, so I just cant see the problem. You can check the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a bit tricky but working solution:

```
@hasSection('fcRadioStyle')
@else

@section('fcRadioStyle')
{{Html::style('css/components/fcradio.css')}}
@stop

@section('styles')
@yield('fcRadioStyle')
@append

@endif
```

This makes by `Form::fcRadio` append this style only once

Answer (score 4):

So this is typically how I deal with it:

In your folder: `resources/views` I create a folder called `layout`. This folder handles the templates for all my pages.

Then I create a file called `default.blade.php`. In it I put the bulk of the HTML code. Here's an example of how `default.blade.php` could look (slimmed down, obviously)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <title>
      @yield('title')
      </title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}">

      <!-- Additional per-page css -->
      @yield('css')
    </head>

    <body>

      @yield('content')

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/script.js"></script>
      <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

      <!-- Include per-page JS -->
      @yield('js')
    </body>

    </html>
```

Right, so essentially what we have so far is the `@yield()` and `asset()` helpers.

`@yield()` is special blade syntax that Laravel uses to say, "Okay. Any time a blade view that is inheriting THIS master template calls the section named in this `@yield()` I will display that content right here.

`asset()` is a nifty little helper that basically appends your URL structure onto the string you pass it. So if your url is `http://MyGreatSite.com` and you use `asset('js/script.js')` it will spit out a fully qualified URL that will work anywhere on the site (http://MyGreatSite.com/js/script.js). `asset()` is great because you can use it in blade templates that will get sent out as an email and all of the files will work in an email inbox because they are absolute links.

Right. So now we have this master template and we need to use it. So what I do is create another view in the `resources/views` directory. Lets say we're doing a contact page. I would make `contact.blade.php`. Now I want to inherit that master template we created. So we do that like so:

```
    @extends('layout.default)

    @section('css')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/contact.css') }}">
    @stop


    @section('title')

    Contact Us

    @stop


    @section('content')

    <h1>Contact us</h1>

    <p>
    Contact us via email: <a href="mailto:contact@mygreatsite.com">contact@mygreatsite.com</a>
    </p>

    @stop


    @section('js')

    <script src="{{ asset('js/contact-form.js') }}"></script>

    @stop
```

Okay, so, first things first. At the very top we tell this blade file that we want to use the template we just made. We use the blade helper `@extends()` and pass it the path to our view relative to the `views` directory separated by periods.

Next, we want to create the sections that correspond to the template. We do that by opening the section with `@section()` and passing the name of the section we want to push this block of content to. We write our content and then we close the section by using `@stop`. Pretty simple. For images, css, or js, we simply use the `asset()` helper again.

I know it's a little long-winded, but hopefully that helps and explains the process a little better.

**tl;dr:** Use `@yield()`, `@section()`, and `asset()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've updated my question to show new problem appeared after applying this solution.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I understand what you are saying.

In your blade layout file create a section inside the head:

```
<head>
    @yield('componentcss')
</head>
```

And in the component do:

```
@section('componentcss')
{{HTML::style('css/fcradio.css')}}
@stop
```

You could also just include the css but I wouldn't advise this:

```
@section('componentcss')
<style>
    .exampleclass {text-align:center;}
</style>
@stop
```

Hopefully I have understood you correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've updated my question to show new problem appeared after applying this solution.

Comment: @DenisSheremet you should've accepted the answer, if it answered your question. Then opened a new question, for the follow up problem.

Comment: @Anthony I've answered this question below by myself, but was unable to accept it due to SO restrictions, now I've accepted it, thanks for reminder.